# Number of social media users in age group in a country vs. population in that age group in a country

Tags: categorical-data, estimation

If you look for the number of instagram users in the UK belonging to the 18-24 year old group you find reports of 5.7million users (see [here](https://napoleoncat.com/stats/instagram-users-in-united_kingdom/2019/04) circa '19). There are only 5.5million 18-24 year olds in the UK (or there were at the time the previous statistic was reported) (see [here](https://www.ons.gov.uk/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/employmentandemployeetypes/timeseries/jn5q/lms)).

What is the reason for this obvious discrepancy? Are these just unreliable statistics or is this a result of people making multiple accounts?

---

Additional information for discussion below:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can think of a few reasons

- multiple accounts as you suggest. As a parent of teenagers I can verify that this happens a lot. Mine have 3 and 4  (that I know of) and their freinds do too.
- younger users pretending to be older. Again, as a parent of teenagers I can verify that this happens a lot.
- older users pretending to be younger.
- bots that register within that age group.
- instagram inflating it's user base.

Comment: are you aware of a way to extract a truer figure for that statistic? I have noticed that Instagram's reporting of 'under-18s' is *definitely* unrealistic. We all know that more than 6% of Instagram's users are 13-17!!!

Comment: I would guess that 6% is an under-estimate. No, sorry I am not aware of any way to get the "true" figures. I hadn't thought about this before until I saw your post. I suppse a lot depends on where napoleoncat gets their numbers from. There may be organistions that do some estimations based on surveys, but even then I would be deeply suspicious.

Comment: The plot now thickens because when I look for a face-to-face study (https://www.statista.com/statistics/536697/instagram-usage-in-uk-by-age-and-gender/) I see that ~65% of Instagram's users are 15-24. This equates to some 19.5mil users. There are only ~8mil 15-24 year olds in the UK. Something very strange is going on here... Unless I am misunderstanding the statistics.

Comment: I think the reasons I gave in my answer would account for that

Comment: I'm not sure. A face-to-face survey wouldn't allow for respondents to manipulate their age. The question posed was not "How many accounts do you have?" but "Do you use Instagram?" This survey was independent and not influenced by Instagram, supposedly. Something must be missing ...

Comment: I see what you mean. Well, I can't access that article, but if that is published in a peer-reviewed journal, and they conclude that 65% of Instagram's UK users are 15-24 and that equates to 19.5m users, then something is evidently wrong, and I can't understand how that would get past peer review. If it's not peer reviewed then I would be exremely doubtful that they used robust methodology. All I can see from the abstract is "71 percent of females aged 15 to 24 years of age use Instagram" - which is clearly something completely different.

Comment: Hmm... I have attached the images given by Ipsos Mori---I'm not sure how reliable they are as pollsters. It's there that they say that 36% of all UK Instagram users are 15-24(???) and that 61% and 71% of 15-24 year old males and females repsectively accessed Instagram within 3 months. I'm not sure if there was a screening question like "Do you have a smartphone and use social media?" (which would make the numbers look higher than reality, maybe).

Comment: Also, I'm still taking the unreliable number of Instagram user's in the UK---which may be influenced by multiple account holders. Although the dataset from Ipsos mori won't be influenced by that, I'm multiplying 65% x ~32mil, where the 32mil dataset is influenced by mutliple accounts. Unsure how to disentangle this problem. Can I simply do 65% * (number of 15-24 yos in the UK e.g. 7.5mil)?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say much about the other study but NapoleonCat works with data fetched directly from the respective social media platforms’ APIs. The data is scanned every day to create monthly statistics and the estimations are based on users’ location declarations and they concern only active users, not the overall number of Facebook accounts.